# Don't quite understand how InputStream.read( byte[], int, int ) works

Tags: java, android, inputstream

I know this is trivial, but it doesn't make sense to me. Java can't pass pointers/references as parameters, yet the read() function is passed a `buffer into which the data is read`, and only returns an int as `the total number of bytes read into the buffer`.

I am expecting to read five separate bytes from this device, but when I pass the function a buffer, and try to access it afterwards it continues to be `null`. If I print out the return value from the function it gives me the `int 5`, which is expected. But how can I access the data which was actually put into the buffer?

Here is a link to the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html)....

EDIT:

This is the original call to the read function.

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected( MenuItem item ) {
    switch( item.getItemId() ) {
    case R.id.connect:
        startActivityForResult( new Intent( this, DeviceList.class ), 1 );
        return true;
    case R.id.readTest:
        Log.i(TAG,  "Before write." );
        byte[] b = {'$'};
        for( int i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++ ) {
            mService.write( b );
        }
        Log.i(TAG, "After write." );
        return true;

    case R.id.readData:
        byte[] c = mService.read( 5 );

        Toast.makeText(this, Integer.toString( mService.bytes ), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    default:
        return super.onContextItemSelected( item );
    }
}
```

Note, this read function is a function declared in my class called BluetoothService. This class contains another class called ConnectedThread, which calls the InputStream read...

Here is MY read function....

```
public byte[] read( int length ) {
    Log.i( TAG, "Inside read." );
    ConnectedThread r;
    buffer = null;
    synchronized( this ) {
        if( mState != STATE_CONNECTED ) return null;
        r = mConnectedThread;
    }
    Log.i(TAG,  "Before run." );
    r.run( length );
    Log.i( TAG, "After run." );
    Log.i( TAG, Integer.toString( bytes ) );
    return buffer;

}
```

And here is the ConnectedThread class, which calls read itself....

```
/**
 * This thread runs during a connection with a remote device.
 * It handles all incoming and outgoing transmissions.
 */
private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final InputStream mmInStream;
    private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

    public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket, String socketType) {
        Log.d(TAG, "create ConnectedThread: " + socketType);
        mmSocket = socket;
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;

        // Get the BluetoothSocket input and output streams
        try {
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "temp sockets not created", e);
        }

        mmInStream = tmpIn;
        mmOutStream = tmpOut;
    }

    public void run(int length) {
        Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectedThread");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];


        // Keep listening to the InputStream while connected
        //while (true) {
            try {
                // Read from the InputStream
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer, 0, length);

                // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity
                mHandler.obtainMessage(MainMenu.MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
                        .sendToTarget();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "disconnected", e);
                connectionLost();
                // Start the service over to restart listening mode
                BluetoothService.this.start();
                //break;
            }
       // }
            Log.i(TAG, "MADE IT HERE" );
    }

    /**
     * Write to the connected OutStream.
     * @param buffer  The bytes to write
     */
    public void write(byte[] buffer) {
        try {
            mmOutStream.write(buffer);

            // Share the sent message back to the UI Activity
            mHandler.obtainMessage(MainMenu.MESSAGE_WRITE, -1, -1, buffer)
                    .sendToTarget();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception during write", e);
        }
    }

    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "close() of connect socket failed", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some code that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: You have to initialize the array. You can't just let it be null from the beginning.

Comment: Ah, thank you AHunger that may be it.

Comment: AHunger Artist, post an answer and I will accept it. Stupid me, but thanks.

Comment: @JuiCe Done. And yeah, it happens :)

Comment: Basically, what goes on is that `read()` replaces (some of) the contents of an existing array, instead of creating a new one. (My guess is this is done for performance reasons, generational GCs might not like frequent allocations of large short-lived objects.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to initialize the array, otherwise it will continue to remain null.

Answer (score 3):

> Java can't pass pointers/references as parameters

Yes it can.

A fundamental misconception like this *would* leave you very confused ...

The way that `read(...)` is supposed to be used is like this:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[42];
int nosRead = is.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
```

You allocate a buffer object and pass it as a parameter to the `read` method.  Bytes are read and copied into the buffer starting at (in this case) offset zero.  When the method call returns, it returns the number of bytes actually read ... and the bytes are in the buffer ready for the caller to process.

As you can see, this *relies* on passing a byte array reference as a parameter to the `read` method.

Comment: How does read determine that next time it has to start read from the last read byte + 1? Here is the code `public int read(byte[] buffer) throws IOException {
        return read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
    }` as this pass 0 as offset so i can't understand how it will determine where to start next?

Comment: You are misunderstanding what `read(...)` does.  It is reading bytes >>into<< the byte array, not taking them out it.  In the case of `read(byte[])` it starts putting the bytes into the array at offset zero ... because that's what we told it to do.

Comment: I understand that `read` is putting the bytes in the array. Referring line from the implementation of `public int read(byte[] buffer, int byteOffset, int byteCount)` **buffer[byteOffset + i] = (byte) c;** and this is how we normally read stream `while((count = is.read(data)) != -1) { total += count; fos.write(data, 0, count); }` In each iteration of while it read the stream and put bytes in the byte[] and in the next iteration it does the same. *1/2*

Comment: What i don't understand how does `read` knows that it has already read some bytes and now it has to start from the next unread bytes. Lets say it read 10 bytes in first iteration in next iteration it has to start from no 11 byte. Where in the code it's being determined. *2/2*

Comment: Under the covers, the input stream keeps track of the unread bytes that it has buffered.  Bear in mind that `InputStream` is effectively an abstract class.  The actual read methods for (say) an input stream that reads from a file or from standard input, are doing other things.  If you look at the code in GrepCode, for example, you can find the relevant descendant classes of `InputStream` where this happens.  In some cases, the tracking of where you are in the stream is actually done by the OS kernel!

Comment: Thanks Stephen for uncovering the undercover mechanics :)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you have a C background that confused you on making the call to read() appropriate. Instead of returning an array or creating one using a pointer to a pointer, read(byte[]) and read(byte[] b, int offset, int len) expect an actual byte array (in the latter form, of size bigger or equal to offset+len) in the argument list. Assuming the value x is returned from the method, the array elements from **offset** to **offset+x-1** will be defined in the array (unless -1 was returned, which indicates an EOF).

Comment: Actually this is a part of Java that mirrors the underlying C API very closely. The C stdlib avoids allocating / freeing memory for you. (IIRC there are some system calls that go against this convention.)